# EC2 Spot instances: How to start tasks, how to stop them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a long batch job that I'd like to run on AWS EC2 Spot Instances, to save money.  However, I can't find the answer to two seemingly critical questions:

1. When a new instance is created, I need to upload the code onto it, configure it, and run the code.  How does that get done for Spot Instances, which are created automatically and unattatendly?
2. When an instance is stopped, I would *prefer* having some type of notification, so that the state could be saved.  (This is not critical, as the batch job will run fine if terminated suddenly - but a clean shutdown is preferred).

What is the standard way to deploy spot instances? Is there a way to do manual setup, turn it into a spot instance, and then let it hibernate until the spot price is available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to #1, if you create an AMI (amazon machine image), you can have everything you want pre-installed on a 'hibernating' image that you can use as a basis for the spot image you start:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances-getting-started.html

For #2, you can be notified when a spot instance terminates using SNS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-autoscaling-notifications.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html

BTW: You can be notified the the instance was terminated, but only **after** it terminates. You can't get notified that an instance is about to be shutdown and gracefully save the state - you need to engineer your solution to be OK with unexpected shutdowns.

> No matter how high you bid, there is always a risk that your Spot
>   Instance will be interrupted. We strongly recommend against bidding
>   above the On-Demand price or using Spot for applications that cannot
>   tolerate interruptions.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-protect-interruptions.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the user data settings to download from a specific repository a script and run it at the first instance startup.
2. As E.J. Brennan said: you can use SNS